# Angular 2 routerLink in parent component relative to child route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have:

- Main component
- -- First-Child component with parameter
- -- Second-Child component

The path of the First-Child and it's parameter:
http://localhost/mpm/0776452c

Second-Child path should be:
http://localhost/mpm/0776452c/settings

My problem is that I want to put the link for Second-Child component in Main component.

I tried this way:
[routerLink]="'./settings'"
but the generated link has round brackets in the end for some reason:
http://localhost/mpm/0776452c/(settings)

Do you have idea how to fix this the easy way, because now I generate full path to Second-Child component ?

Thank you!

**Edit**: 
The link for  Second-Child component is placed in Main component.
The idea is when I'm in First-Child component (http://localhost/mpm/0776452c) I want to click on [routerLink]="'./settings'" which is in Main component so I can go to  http://localhost/mpm/0776452c/settings

**Edit 2** - my router config

```
{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'mpm/:id',
      component: FirstChild,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
      path: 'mpm/:id/settings',
      component: SecondChild,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem a little bit more? What do you mean by "put the link" ? Do you need to use the new link in first child component? Like, getting "settings" parameter into first child?

Comment: The link for  Second-Child component is placed in Main component.
The idea is when I'm in First-Child component (http://localhost/mpm/0776452c) I want to click on [routerLink]="'./settings'" which is in Main component so I can go to  http://localhost/mpm/0776452c/settings

Comment: Hey, can you post here your router configs? I'm really interested why its putting those brackets. Second idea, you can navigate to id/settings within the routerlink.(07xxx/settings) I think router is kinda confused about the state.

Comment: I updated my question. I already implemented solution, but I want to know is there other way.

Comment: As Steveadoo said you could make secondchild a child of first child, then router should do this automagically. Or generate full path, i don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "./settings" as your route, it's going to try to navigate to a child of FirstComponent, you need to use "../settings", but even that won't work.

You'll probably have to rework how you do the way your routes work, and make SecondComponent a child of FirstComponent in the routes.

If you try to navigate to ../settings, the parent route is going to be /mpm, so it'll resolve to /mpm/settings, not /mpm/:id/settings. The only other way it could work is if you change your routerLink to something like:

`routerLink="../{{id}}/settings"`

P.S, if you don't want to bind to a value, you can omit the brackets. That way you don't have to wrap your values in quotes.

Comment: i think following both should work `[routerLink]='../../mpm/{{id}}/settings'`  or `[routerLink]='/mpm/{{id}}/settings'`